# Retrofit 2 GET/POST doesn't work for large data in Android

Tags: android, post, get, retrofit, retrofit2

I have seen other threads for this issue but unable to get any proper answer.

```
@POST("task/GetAllTasks")
Call<MyTask> getMyTasks(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Query("EmployeeId") String emp);
```

This is how I am calling, at first I thought it is due to **GET** request data limitation because GET imposes data limits and then I changed request from GET to POST but issue still persists.

```
ApiUtils.getTaskService().getMyTasks(apiToken, employeeId).enqueue(new Callback<MyTask>() {
@Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MyTask> call, Response<MyTask> response) {
   // ... Successful code goes here
 }

@Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MyTask> call, Throwable t) {
        //.. This block of code executing now :(
  }
 }
```

Always `onFailure` is being called. I have tested this same request on Postman and it is returning data. Content-Length is **content-length →45720**

It does work on small amount of data as I have tested it on Dev database which has smaller amount of data but on Live environment it is continuously causing problem.

Please suggest a solution or should I leave Retrofit and move to native Android library for this?

**EDIT:** Can we increase request timeout in Retrofit, if yes then how?

Comment: Post full stacktrace dude. It's hard to guess what happened without stacktrace

Comment: Facing this exception `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to increase your timeout:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                  .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                  .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
```

And set it to your retrofit:

`new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("xxx").client(client).build().create(xxx.class)`;

Comment: Yes, you are right, increasing timeout fixes the problem.

Comment: Damm....I'm implementing paging library, hence using retrofit for the first time, I didn't know about this. I was search for every possible error and debugging while biting my nails for last 2 hrs and finally got to know that due to short timeout, all this is happening. Goddamn

Comment: @SambitMallick it is better to apply paging because increasing timeout means your user have to wait for seconds to get data fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Part to send big string data it can easily send your data to server side

For ex.
You need to send some string that name is "abc" then in the retrofit code

@Part("abc") //your string variable

Its works for me and I save that data to mediumtext in mysql
and the code is $_REQUEST['abc'];